# Below which energy would the weak interaction become confining?

Tags: weak-interaction, electroweak, confinement

[Claudson et al](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.34.873) considered an alternative formulation of the standard model where the SU(2) interaction was strengthened to become confining below ≈ 300 GeV, *above* the electroweak scale.

Consider if the scale at which the Higgs broke electroweak symmetry were instead lowered (or removed altogether, if no answer would exist otherwise, but keeping massive fermions by some other means).  When would the weak interaction become confining?

Comment: In the absence of fermions, if I remember right, there would not be any phase transition separating the Higgs and confinement phases. When a chiral coupling to fermions is introduced, I don't know what happens to that picture (hence the comment), but https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.06201, https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04814, https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.01485 might have some references that could lead you to helpful information.

Comment: The abstract of "Higgs and confinement phases in the fundamental SU(2) Higgs model: Mean field analysis" (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370269385900449) says: "The phase diagram of the four-dimensional SU(2) gauge-Higgs model with Higgs field in the fundamental representation is derived... the analytic connection between Higgs and confinement phases breaks down for sufficiently small values of the quark Higgs coupling, indicating that the Higgs and confinement phases for these couplings are strictly distinct phases." That might be only for non-chiral couplings, though.